# LMI reformulation

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

In [Data-driven stabilization of discrete-time control-affine nonlinear systems: a Koopman operator approach](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2203.14114), I read that the following LMI

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbb{U}^{\top} P \mathbb{U}-P & 0 & \mathbb{U}^{\top} P B & k \\
0 & -P & P B & 0 \\
B^{\top} P \mathbb{U} & B^{\top} P & -\varepsilon P & 0 \\
k^{\top} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{\varepsilon} I
\end{array}\right) \prec 0$$

can be reformulated to

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{U}^{\top} P \mathbb{U}-P & \mathbb{U}^{\top} P B & k \\
B^{\top} P \mathbb{U} & B^{\top} PB-\varepsilon P & 0 \\
k^{\top} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\varepsilon} I
\end{array}\right) \prec 0$$

via the Schur complement. This reformulation is not obvious for me. Can anyone please help me with this reformulation? Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schur complement is performed with respect to the 2nd row/column. First note that the matrix inequality is equivalent to

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbb{U}^{\top} P \mathbb{U}-P & \mathbb{U}^{\top} P B & k & 0\\
B^{\top} P \mathbb{U} &  -\varepsilon P & 0 & B^{\top} P\\
k^{\top} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\varepsilon} I & 0\\
0 & P B &0& -P \\
\end{array}\right) \prec 0 .$$

A Schur complement with respect to the last row/column yields

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbb{U}^{\top} P \mathbb{U}-P & \mathbb{U}^{\top} P B & k\\
B^{\top} P \mathbb{U} &  -\varepsilon P & 0\\
k^{\top} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\varepsilon} I\\
\end{array}\right)-\begin{pmatrix}0\\B^\top P\\0\end{pmatrix}(-P)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}0 & P B &0\end{pmatrix} \prec 0$$

from which the result follows.

As a matter of fact, it is always easier (at least at the beginning) to permute rows and columns you want to perform a Schur complement with at the end of the matrix and then use the standard formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The hint of permutation is really helpful!